# After effects to trim video using expression

Tags: after-effects

I want to write an expression to trim the video in after effects with start and end times to trim that particular video.

can anybody help me? Any reference point to write an expression would be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wondering if you could give me a bit more info on what you are hoping to achieve. When you say 'trim' the video, are you talking about a layer in your composition? Or do you mean you want to control the start and end time of your render? 
Either way, it sounds more like something that would be controlled with a script as opposed to an expression.

Answer (score 0):

expressions in after effects don't know how to change layers, they just read data. unless it's not enough for you to set a timeRemap and write an expression in it that would just start playing from a certain time (effect("Slider Control")("Slider") + time), but the layer itself will not change. and the playback will be from the beginning of the layer

in order to somehow trim the layer, you need to use scripts.